# How to Create Custom Command in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal, command

I'm new to Linux and I'm wondering if I can create custom Linux commands:
For Example

```
LearningPhase1 cpu getinfo
```

To show similar output as we get from lscpu command

```
LearningPhase1 memory getinfo
```

to get memory information of my Computer

Also, I want to know if I can create new user using my own custom command

```
LearningPhase1 user create <username>
```

To create new user

```
LearningPhase1 user list
```

To get all the users of my computer

```
LearningPhase1 user list --sudo-only
```

To get the users with sudo permissions

This is my question on stackoverflow.
Any Link, Material, or Help regarding this will be much appreciated.
Please Help me in Learning more about these things.

Answer (score 1):

Linux shells looking for programs which are stored in **Specific Locations** and if there is a program named `LearningPhase1`, they execute it as command.

you have to write your program and put its **binaries** or its **code** (if its interpreted) in those specific location.

you can view those specific locations with this:

```
echo $PATH
```